# Magento2 Error when serach using 2 variables

Tags: magento2

I am getting following error

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log.
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_renderFilters() called at [app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php:415]
#2 Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->_renderFilters() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php:1167
```

This happens when search keywords are less then 3 as 3 is defined in admin, above this everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and the only quick solution to resolve the above exception/error was to change the Catalog Search Minimal Query Length to 1.

Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search > Minimal Query Length